# update database when a user shared a link to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to update database once a user shared a link in my website?

Such as,some points will be awarded to their account if they shared the link.

And how can I ensure that they really share the link to facebook but not just click share then close the popup window...

I'm not familiar with facebook , and tried google it just now but still didn't find the answer...

Thank you.

Edit:

```
   <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
    type="text/javascript">
   </script>

   <a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="script2.php?id=XXX">
```

Comment: can you tell me which plugins are you using to share? i mean `like` and what else? are you using `feed` post also?

Comment: @bool.dev Thanks for your reply.Sorry I not really understand but I'm just using the share button code provided by facebook developer in my php script.

Comment: @bool.dev Thank you.I put the code in question.

Comment: great, thats the older share button which has been replaced by like button, i'll still try and figure out something if it's possible.

Comment: @bool.dev I see,thank you so much,I will check for it too.

Comment: i couldn't figure out anything for the share button, you can check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ to see that they have deprecated share, and recommend using the Like button. You can easily track likes.

Comment: @bool.dev Can Like button share the link too?I mean if click like it will automatically shared on your wall.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6157/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-irene-ling)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update(Aug 21, 2013)**: Facebook's api has changed since the time this was originally posted. The way to track likes is still the same (*read original answer below*), but the status of the share button has changed.

The deprecation message/info. is no longer visible anywhere in the docs, but it can be seen in [this bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252983554810810/). The share button still seems to be usable according to [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/). But there is no direct way from facebook to track a share. I'm not aware of any hacks to track shares either.

---

**Original answer:**

From Facebook docs at [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/).

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and will no longer be supported.
>   Please use the Like button whenever possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

So I'll tell you how to do it for a like button:

#### First use the [Javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    // you can subscribe to events here
    // edge.create event is fired only when the user likes (which means that the wall post has already happened, when the like button was clicked) 
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
   function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            // you can do some ajax call to your backend and update your database
   }
); 
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
  </script>
```

#### Somewhere in your page include the like button

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com/fblike/" 
     send="true" width="450" show_faces="false"
     >
</fb:like>
```

You can also change the word that is displayed in the like button, from like to recommend, you should try and auto-generate your like button code from this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and links , I will try it out now.Thanks again for your patient.Wish you have a nice day.

Comment: Glad i could help, there are some things about the javascript sdk that you'll have to figure out before you can implement it properly and completely, so read more about the javascript sdk too.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are looking for this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
You need to subscribe this event.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

**Example Link:**

`<a href="?share=YOUR+URL">SHARE TO FACEBOOK</a>`

**Example code to proses**

```
if(isset($_GET['share']))
{
    if(mysql_query("insert into table X() value()"))
    {
        //open window, you can use header('location:..') or meta redirect or another way, in this sample i'm using javascript window.open;
        echo '<script>window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.urlencode($_GET['share']).'","share","width=600,height=400");</script>';
    }
}
```

To implementing facebook "Like" button, [this link](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2798622/facebook-like-button-callback) maybe can help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I'm still looking for a way to handle if the user really share a link.

Comment: but what if the user does not share the link.. ? the db entry would be invalid

Answer (score 1):

You do not need facebook, you could just have a Javascript AJAX call executed when someone clicks the Like button on your page. The call writes to your database. Just bin a click event to the button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How about share?I'm wonder how if they just click the share button but didn't exactly share it(just close the popup share window)..

Comment: In that case you will need some API to the link sharing platform, because the user is technically leaving your site.

Comment: Hmmm...how can I do that? Is there any example?