# How to count facebook likes into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-like

I have this project I'm working on (php mysql), it contains blocks of movies that can be shared through facebook like. The thing is that I want to count the facebook likes into DATABASE (which is movies table and users favourite table).

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8645979/720508 , it should help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked through the facebook developer docs? Using the javascript api you can use methods such as "edge.subscribe" to call a function when people click like. This would then allow you to make an ajax request. The first part of this document describes this scenario

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Hello, i've checked this topic as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640392/update-database-when-a-user-shared-a-link-to-facebook/8645979#8645979 . The answer seems to be perfect, i'm just having hard time understanding how to use javascript SDK to trigger php insert into sql function, do i need to use php sdk as well? Or diffrent option?

Comment: Does your url contain something that would uniquely identify it? If so you could look at something like jquery's ajax function to get started with making an ajax call

Comment: Yes it does, cause link for each element is generated inside (it contains get parameter which is variable in that case). I still don't understand how to get this whole method started.