# Like button doesn't actually 'like' the page

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I have tried all three different options facebook lets you use when embedding a facebook like button but when I like a page it appears to have added the +1 but when I refresh the page the 'like' doesn't stay. It also doesn't appear in my timeline.

```
<div class="sm-facebook">
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://mysite.com/blog/blog-post&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=277475035619415"></iframe>                
</div>
```

Comment: if you don't mind the xfbml version, then check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640392/update-database-when-a-user-shared-a-link-to-facebook/8645979#8645979 , not exactly related to your question, but it might give you some pointers.

Comment: Ensure the href link you are using is lintable (accessible externally). Try putting it into [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and see what it throws out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mysite.com/blog/blog-post is an invalid URL.  I get nothing.  Try it for yourself at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.  It has 1 critical, 1 error and multiple warnings.  Fix those up and it should work fine.

Comment: That was just a sample link. Turns out I was missing fb:admins and fb:app_id from my meta tags.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  Did the debugger tool help?